# Binomial distribution's cumulative distribution function question

Tags: binomial-distribution

Can someone please help me on how this solution gives 50 as a result?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it:

```
Show[
 DiscretePlot[
  Probability[X > 10, 
   X \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[M, .1]], {M, 30, 60}],
 Plot[.01, {M, 0, 60}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus you can confirm: $M\leq 50$.